How to link a Flutter app with a Rust static library using CMakeLists.txt on Windows?
I'm trying to link a Rust static library to my Flutter app on Windows using CMake. The app compiles, but when I try to call a function from the Rust library in Dart, I get an error saying the function cannot be found.
I am trying to link my Flutter app to a Rust static library on Windows using CMakeLists.txt. I am adding the following lines to either windows/CMakeLists.txt or windows/runner/CMakeLists.txt:
target_include_directories(${BINARY_NAME} PRIVATE "path/to/.h_file/release/include") 
target_link_libraries(${BINARY_NAME} PRIVATE "path/to/static_lib/release/lib/rust_static_lib.lib")

The app compiles without any issues, but when I try to call a function from the library in Dart using:
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

typedef SayHelloFunc = Pointer<Utf8> Function();
typedef FreeStringFunc = Void Function(Pointer<Utf8>);
typedef FreeStringFuncDart = void Function(Pointer<Utf8>);

final rust_lib = DynamicLibrary.executable();

final SayHelloFunc SayHello =
    rust_lib.lookupFunction<SayHelloFunc, SayHelloFunc>("say_hello");
final FreeStringFuncDart FreeStr =
    rust_lib.lookupFunction<FreeStringFunc, FreeStringFuncDart>("free_str");

String get_message() {
    Pointer<Utf8> message = SayHello();
    String dart_str = message.toDartString();
    FreeStr(message);
    return dart_str;
}

I get the following error:
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'say_hello': The specified procedure could not be found. (error code: 127))

Here's my Rust code:
use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
use std::os::raw::c_char;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn say_hello() -> *mut c_char {
    let hello_msg = CString::new("hello from rust!").unwrap();
    hello_msg.into_raw()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn free_str(str: *mut c_char) {
    if !str.is_null() {
        unsafe {
            CString::from_raw(str);
        }
    }
}

And my Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "dart_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "rust_static_lib"
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "staticlib"]

[dependencies]

my .h file, but I don't think it affects anything.
#ifndef RUST_STATIC_LIB_H
#define RUST_STATIC_LIB_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

const char* say_hello();
void free_str(char* str);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // RUST_STATIC_LIB_H

I have no problems with .dll files and .so files. Only with static linking
